# Отправка данных формы с вложениями ajax

Tags: php, ajax, xhr

Делаю отправку формы с вложениями без перезагрузки страницы.
Инпут для файлов на стороне формы

```
<form class="tabs-section__new-task-form" id="newTaskForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="task__attach" class="task-num-file" multiple="multiple">
//остальной хтмл
```

За отправку отвечает этот код

```
 $('#task_submit').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = [];
        // data[0] = $('#newTaskForm').serializeArray();
        var form = document.forms.newTaskForm;
            console.log(form);
        data = new FormData(form);
        $.each( files, function( key, value ){
            data.append( key, value );
        });
var form = document.forms.newTaskForm;
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/Controllers/dashboard.php");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if(xhr.status == 200) {
                        data = xhr.responseText;
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data == "true") {
                            // $(".sending").replaceWith("<p>Принято!<p>");
                            alert("ok");
                        } else {
                            // $(".sending").replaceWith("<p >Ошибка! Обновите страницу...<p>");
                            alert("ne ok");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
```

отправляю несколько аттачей за раз, на стороне php есть этот код

```
if (isset($_POST['addTask'])):
    $val = false;
    print_r($_POST);
    echo('<hr>');
    print_r($_FILES);
    ....//собираю строго определенные инпуты
    //перебираю теперь свои аттачи
    foreach ($_FILES["task__attach"] as $file):
            var_dump($file);
        endforeach;
```

До этого перебираю все свои вложения на стороне фронта

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        files = (this.files);
    });
```

Сервер возвращает только последний файл, хотя по идее он в foreach должен получить все аттачи.
Вот скрин ответа:
[![скрин ответа][1]][1]

Не знаю как можно решить данную проблему, и в чем ее причина.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlCQY.png

Comment: <input type="file" name="task__attach[]" ...

Answer (score 0):

Помог комментарий @Kirill

```
<input type="file" name="task__attach[]" ....>
```